# Локальный удаленный доступ Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как или с помощью чего можно получить доступ(как по TeamViewer) с одного ПК(Ubuntu) на другой(Ubuntu) по локальной сети?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

с помощь программ Remmina, vnc.

Необходимо поставить на машину, к которой будет производиться подключение, vnc-server, на вторую машину поставить remmina. На хостовой машине запустить vnc-server (команда vncserver). На клиентской машине запустить remmina (имеет графический интерфейс) и по vnc подключиться к хостовой машине.

Comment: Вопрос ТС - как? Не только "с помощью чего?".

Comment: Необходимо поставить на машину, к которой будет производиться подключение, vnc-server, на вторую машину поставить remmina. Запустить remmina и по vnc подключиться к нужной машине.

Comment: @Fitstd Вам на примере vnc показать?

Comment: @0xdb , если можно, то пожалуйста.

Comment: @Exz0rcist См. комменатрий ТС. Перенесити ваш комментарий кнопкой править в тело ответа. Дополните, при необходимости, примером запуска сервера/клиента.